# MATLAB: building gradient between two columns in greyscale image

Tags: matlab, image-processing, binary, gradient, grayscale

I have two images, one of which is a greyscale image (orig), the other is a binary image of the same size with vertical lines (mask). Where the binary value is 1 I would like on the grey scale to create a gradient from the two columns of values on either side of the binary line. For example:

```
binary:            old greyscale:         new greyscale:
0 0 1 1 1 0 0      x  10  x  x  x  6   x        x  10  9  8  7   6   x
0 0 1 1 1 0 0      x  1   x  x  x  5   x        x  1   2  3  4   5   x
0 0 1 1 1 0 0      x  5   x  x  x  13  x        x  5   7  9  11  13  x
0 0 1 1 1 0 0      x  10  x  x  x  2   x        x  10  8  6  4   2   x
```

I have the following code so far...not sure if its of any value...it runs through and finds the x location of the start of a vertical streak in vectempa, width in vectempb, and then the value from the greyscale on either side in vectemp1 and vectemp2. Current plan is to take the absolute value of difference of each column in vectemp1 and vectemp2, divide by that column in vectempb (width), and then use that to increment the gradient...somehow accounting for direction of the gradient. Does this make sense or is there a much better/easier way to do this?

```
vectempa=[];
vectempb=[];
vectemp1=[];
vectemp2=[];
q=1;
r=1;
for i=1:x
    if mask(1,i)==0 && mask(1,(i+1))==1
        vectempa(end+1)=i;
        vectemp1(1:z,q)=orig((1:z),i);
        q=q+1;
    elseif mask(1,i)==1 && mask(1,(i+1))==0
        vectempb(end+1)=i-vectempa(end);
        vectemp2(1:z,r)=orig((1:z),i);
        r=r+1;
    end
end
```

Thanks!

[image]

[image]

Comment: Should the last row of the expected result be `x 10 8 6 4 2 x`? I'm not sure why that row was omitted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it possible you are looking for [`roifill`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/roifill.html)?

```
new = roifill( old, mask );
```

Comment: yup, that or regionfill...knew this had to be a thing already. Thanks!

Comment: Does `roifill / regionfill` do this gradient scaling in between the columns?  I'm asking for curiosity as I actually don't know what the behaviour is when filling in values delineated by masks.

Comment: @rayryeng it might be the case that `roifill` will interpolate across rows... in that case, not sure it is exactly what the OP is looking for... However, if (s)he is looking for making the streaks go away, than `roifill` is a good choice.